# Qual a diferença entre pip install e pip install env?

Tags: python, pycharm, pip

Sou novo na programação, vi que para instalar módulos se usa pip install + nome do módulo. Andei pesquisando e vi que tinha dois modos, tem alguma diferença neles ou tanto faz? Sou novo na programação, vi que para instalar módulos se usa pip install + nome do módulo. Andei pesquisando e vi que tinha dois modos, tem alguma diferença neles ou tanto faz?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Não existem um modo `pip install env`. Esse comando vai simplesmente instalar o pacote [env](https://pypi.org/project/env/).

Answer (score -4):

Utilize 'pip install + nome_do_modulo'.

A outra é para criar ambientes virtuais.
Você pode saber mais sobre Ambiente  Virtual em https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/understanding-virtual-environments-in-python--cms-28272

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `pip install env` não tem nada a ver com criar ambientes virtuais.

Comment: @sourcream não vou entrar em detalhes sobre outros Sistemas Operacionais mais em questão do Ubuntu 20.04 para você criar um Ambiente  Virtual  será necessária baixar o Virtualenv através  do pip e geralmente os comandos são: pip install virtualenv OU pip install venv

Embora seja esse os nomes, muitas pessoas costumam chamar de env também.
<br>
Obs: Caso minha resposta esteja erra é só usar seu conhecimento para responder a dúvida do @MaxDias!